# Device recognized as ????? in ubuntu

Tags: adb, linux, motorola-droid

Hello good people of stack exchange, I am having trouble setting up my Ubuntu 11.04 boot to use for app development on a hardware device. I have followed the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) to try and recongnize the phone. However, when I run ADB devices or in eclipse, the device is listed as ?????? and can not be used to install an app to. Any advice?

Comment: What device are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you ran adb as an underprivileged user. So when adb server starts, it does not have the permissions to run read/write to the device. First you have to kill the server, and then restart it as root:

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server

Then you can run this as any user:
adb devices
```

Comment: You don't always have to run adb as root to start the server, but it's a lot faster when you're dealing with a lot of devices.

Answer (score 1):

What number are you using for your udev? I wrote about my experiences with my HTC sensation here: http://colinwren.com/using-your-htc-sensation-to-debug-android-apps-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-using-udev-and-adb/

As stated by aspitzer use sudo to start the adb server. Also make sure you've got the correct device code. You can find this by using `lsusb` and looking at the code given here (use the first 4 characters)

Comment: (Note that referring to other answers as "above" or "below" isn't helpful as the answers can be sorted in numerous ways, not just chronological.)

Comment: +1 . I got caught there too when I assumed that the vendor id for my nexus s would be Samsung. In fact it's Google. The command is lsusb.

Comment: amended answer for both of these.

Comment: Note that first is the vendor code and the second is the product code: the latter changes depending on the mode you are in.

Answer (score 0):

When I've experienced that, I've had to [kill adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#stopping) and restart it with sudo.  You might have to sudo the rest of your adb commands as well.